# XAMPP: apache won't start but already running in port 80?

Tags: apache, xampp

Not a serious problem, and easily solved. Just a curious question.

I'm running Linux Mint, and am trying to build a website using a small database. To this end, I've installed XAMPP. Previously it worked fine, but then I started running into problems (browser is downloading .php files, even though files have the correct permissions.)
However, since I reinstalled XAMPP, I can't get Apache to start.
So after reading some forums, I try to see why not, by looking at what is occupying port 80.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80           :::*     LISTEN      1414/apache2
```

So it seems that apache was already running. Killing the process allows me to start Apache up via the XAMPP GUI, but I was wondering why it would start up before I start up XAMPP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you already installed LAMP. Check if Apche is installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstal | grep apache
```

You might get this:

```
apache2                     install
apache2-bin                 install
apache2-data                install
apache2-mpm-prefork         install
apache2-mpm-worker          install
libapache2-mod-fastcgi      install
libapache2-mod-php5         install
```

Comment: ah, that seems to be it. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome please do no t forget to mark the answer